# Debian 9 booting into grub, kernel missing

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub, hardware-failure

I'm in a new company and we've got the following problem:

Our complete monitoring (zabbix) is, or rather was, running on an old Debian 9 machine, with no backups.

Yesterday, the machine just started booting into grub instead of the OS. We have spent 2 days trying to find a solution, but everything was in vain.

Trying to boot from grub, we identified the correct partition (Which is msdos formatted, don't ask me why, I didn't do it), snooped around a bit and noticed the kernel file in /boot had vanished. there was only /boot/grub.

Next, we booted into a Live Ubuntu and did the whole chroot shebang, which did work. However, when trying to use apt to reinstall the kernel/linux, it just throws a segmentation fault. ANY apt command throws a segmentation fault for that matter. Probably other applications will too. I also did a grub-update for good measure, but that didn't help either (which was foreseeable as the kernel file is still missing).

My consensus after this ordeal is that the Hardware, probably HDD, must be faulty. I'm going to get all the zabbix files and database off the device as quick as possible, for the cases that the worst happens and the machine is not salvageable and maybe, hopefully, somehow be able to salvage the monitoring system.

Do any of you have any more ideas as to what we could try? This is a BIG problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have most likely accurately identified the problem as being one of hardware. At least, that's the most plausible explanation for the segmentation faults.

You may wish to boot this system into [memtest86+](https://www.memtest.org/) (BIOS boot) or [memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) (EFI boot). Your mention of an "MSDOS boot partition" suggests probably EFI, as in that case `/boot/efi` is a `vfat` (Microsoft) filesystem. Memory fault is a very common cause of spurious segmentation faults, though it could instead/also be motherboard or CPU.

As for why your kernel disappeared, that is more of a mystery. Faulty storage doesn't generally cause individual files to simply disappear. I suggest having a look in your `/var/log/dpkg.log` (and `dpkg.log.1`, `dpkg.log.2.gz`, etc) to see if you can spot when/why a package matching the name `linux-image-*` was removed.

Comment: Hi grifferz, I checked the dpkg logs but could not find anything. I found out the kernel version and tried reinstalling it, which gave another segmentation fault. Here is the output of dpkg -C: https://pastebin.com/8rALwK3K